# Pass the value of checkbox of component1 to filter pipe a list on component2 angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, filter

I have two questions:

1) I have a component with a list and a functional filter when click a checbox, but only can filter if that checbox is inside the same component of list, but i want create a component just for the checkbox.

2) Now im just able to true or false of checkbox but i want to pass a value when checked.

```
Plunker with example:
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/629mV0jrOjwMHr9RZxRZ?p=preview

Comment: I tried add the checkbox component as a Directive on the list component,

Answer (score 1):

You had some problems with your plunker and it was not working correctly.

First of all bootstrapping both components, you should only bootstrap `AppComponent`.

Secondly, your `Output` annotation should look like this:

```ts
@Output() checked: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

Other than this, the only problem was that you were using the wrong variable in `AppComponent`. In component you were using `checked`, even though your filter pipe was using variable `check`. So change your variable to `check` and you are good to go :)

```ts
check:boolean = false;

trataCheck(event) {
 this.check = event;
}
```

Your **[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/1bpu8WmmInbwENOoorTz?p=preview)**